# Building FIPS module on sparc 64bit solaris 9

Tags: solaris, sparc, fips

Building the FIPS module on sparc 64-bit is generating a 32-bit 
binary.  The following message is in the output when "./config" is invoked:

```
WARNING! If you wish to build 64-bit library, then you have to 
             invoke './Configure solaris64-sparcv9-cc' *manually*.
```

Even on running the above command directly, the code is breaking at "make" step with error:

```
ld: fatal: file ../../crypto/sha/sha1-sparcv9.o: wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS32
ld: fatal: File processing errors. No output written to ../fips_standalone_sha1
```

Comment: "The FIPS module" is vague and unspecified - this could apply to many different encryption packages.

Comment: @alanc, I was building FIPS v2.0.5 provided by openSSL

Answer (score 1):

I was able to do this by following steps

```
#export KERNEL_BITS=64
#./config no-asm
```